# Google.GData.Contacts adding contacts to Gapps

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I am trying to add contact to Gapps contact. I tried bellow code. Its adding contact to Google account successfully without any error. But its not displaying the added contact in the account. Here is my code for adding contact

`

```
                 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {   
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret
                },
                Scopes = new string[] { "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" },

                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            var token = credential.Token.AccessToken;


            string RedirectURI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                // Note: AccessToken is valid only for 60 minutes
                AccessToken = token,
                RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken,
                RedirectUri = RedirectURI
            };

            RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings(
                "AppName", parameters);
            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);


                Contact newContact = new Contact();

                newContact.Name = new Name()
                {
                    FullName = "Elizabeth Bennet",
                    GivenName = "Elizabeth",
                    FamilyName = "Bennet",
                };
                newContact.Content = "Notes";
                // Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
                newContact.Emails.Add(new EMail()
                {
                    Primary = true,
                    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
                    Address = "something@gmail.com"
                });
                newContact.Emails.Add(new EMail()
                {
                    Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
                    Address = "something@gmail.com"
                });

                newContact.Location = "Pune";
                Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));


                Contact createdContact = cr.Insert(feedUri, newContact); // Is Successfull 

            }`
```

When I fetch the contacts it gives me added contact in the result. Please suggest the solution for the issue.

```
string str = createdContact.Id;

                Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
                foreach (Contact c in f.Entries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.Name.FullName);
                }
```

Thanks;
Renuka.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all contacts by sending  [***GET request***](https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/%7BuserEmail%7D/full) but before that, you need to request access using OAuth 2.0. Your application needs the scope information. 
Please be mindful in every request that you send using Google Contacts API, specify the version number, use the GData-Version HTTP header.
The version **1** and **2** of the Google Contacts API has been officially **deprecated**. We encourage you to use version 3. **Version 3** of the API introduces new structured data formats for the contact's name and structured postal address fields
For more details regarding Contact Entry, follow this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#contact_entry